# Store App Dashboard: GridView and Multiple Charts

Tags: windows, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I'm working on a Store app that consists of several charts. I've already developed the charts and have them rendering using the chart control in the various forms.

I have been asked to bring these together in an app that allows the user to scroll left and right through each of the charts.

Every example I have found for using a GridView data binds the content of the GridView to item templates.

What I'm trying to get my head round is how I could please these chart controls directly in to a GridView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Roy

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question you need to have charts as items in a grid view.
If this is what you want, I have dome this before using charts from 3rd party toolkit.

- You need ( may be variable sized) templates with each item having a different template of its own.
- You need a items list with data for all the charts.
- Then upon runtime you need to assign the template to each item.